# Access to operands and operations from IA32 in Linux

Tags: x86, addressing-mode

I'm getting a bit confused with this homework i have to do for college, i understand what a register is, why to put some bytes in the memory or in the register, but would be a great help to give me a push on this first exercise:

(Gnu assembly):

```
| address  || Value |
|  0x100   || 0xFF  |
|  0x104   || 0xAB  |
|  0x108   || 0x13  |
|  0x10C   || 0x11  |


| Register|| Value |
|  %eax   || 0x100 |
|  %ecx   ||  0x1  |
|  %edx   ||  0x3  |
```

Fill out the following table with the corresponding values for the operands indicated:

```
|  Operand     || Value |
|   %eax       ||
|   0x104      ||
|  $0x108      ||
|  (%eax)      ||
|  4(%eax)     ||
| 9(%eax,%edx) ||
|260(%ecx,%edx)||
|0xFC(,%ecx,4) ||
|(%eax,%edx,4) ||
```

What i can tell by looking at this is that the first operand has the hexadecimal value of **0x100** and is a register, the second one i can't tell because has nothing before, the third operand has a dollar flag, i read it's an immediate operand, can't tell what value it gets.

The 4(%eax) it's probably a memory address with the 4 being the displacement, from this point i have no idea...

I hope i was as clear as necessary to understand what my doubts are, and thanks very much for any help provided.

Kind Regards,
Souza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need to look up the AT&T syntax. [Here](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~xlanchen/cailiao/x86%20Assembly%20Programming.htm) is a short description of how to interpret AT&T syntax memory operands (under **"AT&T Style Syntax"**).